# Getting Error : Unescaped '-' in jshint

Tags: javascript

`var string = (/[^\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF-\s]/gi);`

Unescaped '-'.

Please try to solve this error.

Regards,

TEjas Savaliya

Comment: Please edit _this_ question to indicate the issues you're having instead of asking the same question repeatedly (with slightly different errors). Also, include the code that's throwing it, and more background .. and I'm sure we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = (/[^\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF\-\s]/gi);
```

`\s` is a set of characters so you can't do a range to it, meaning the `-\s` doesn't make sense, and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hint. Likely you want that hyphen. Yet the last one, in the "range" `-\s`, it seems to be invalid. Are you sure you don't want to omit it, and just match `\s`? If not, better escape it with a backslash as it's in the middle of a character class.