# Got Bad escapement Error in jshint

Tags: javascript, regex, jshint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Error : Unescaped ‘-’ in jshint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196436/getting-error-unescaped-in-jshint)

Line 3: `var iChars = "!@#$%^&*+=[]\\\;{}|\":<>?";`
Bad escapement.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. If you have a _question_, however, please edit this to include the code in question, and provide a bit more background. If you can do that, please flag for moderator review.

Comment: @TimPost Seems to be one of three similar and v.low quality questions; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197758/getting-error-unescaped and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196436/getting-error-unescaped-in-jshint . Bordering on abuse.

Answer (score 3):

`;` doesn't require escaping, so `\;` is a bad escape sequence.

```
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*+=[]\\\;{}|\":<>?";
//                          ^--- this backslash is the problem
```

Just remove the backslash before the `;`:

```
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*+=[]\\;{}|\":<>?";
```

Comment: so it should be: `var iChars = "!@#$%^&*+=[]\\;{}|\":<>?";`

Comment: @bidifx: I would have thought it was obvious, but I added it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `\\\`, just `\\`.