# Getting Error Unescaped '-'

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Error : Unescaped ‘-’ in jshint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196436/getting-error-unescaped-in-jshint)

```
Line 5: var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
```

Getting Error: `Unescaped '-'`.

Does anyone know where and what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

Hyphens in character classes need escaping, they are metacharacters there.

```
/^([\w\-]+(?:\.[\w\-]+)*)@((?:[\w\-]+\.)*\w[\w\-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[\w-]
```

that character cannot appear unescaped in char classes

usually you would use it like this `[a-z]`